# Comparison between Point And EmptyRegion

Tags: evaluation, regions

My aim is to evaluate the length of a line segment lying inside a sphere.

**Code**

```
line = Line[{{2, 2, 2}, {-3, -3, -3}}];
sphere = Sphere[];
pts = RegionIntersection[line, sphere];
If[pts == EmptyRegion[3], 0, RegionMeasure[Line @@ pts, 1]]
```

**Problem**

When there is an intersection, the output is a non-evaluated expression

> ```
>  If[
>    Point[
>      {{1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}, 
>       {-(1/Sqrt[3]), -(1/Sqrt[3]), -(1/Sqrt[3])}}] == EmptyRegion[3], 
>    0, 
>    RegionMeasure[Line @@ pts, 1]]
> ```

Why doesn't the `==` evaluate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `===` instead of `==`:

```
If[pts===EmptyRegion[3],0,RegionMeasure[Line@@pts,1]]
```

> 2

On the other hand, it would be much simpler to use `Ball[]` instead of `Sphere[]` (and use [`ArcLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength) to get the measure of dimension 1):

```
ArcLength @ RegionIntersection[
    Line[{{2,2,2}, {-1,-1,-1}}],
    Ball[]
]

ArcLength @ RegionIntersection[
    Line[{{2,2,2}, {3,3,3}}],
    Ball[]
]

ArcLength @ RegionIntersection[
    Line[{{2,2,2}, {0,0,0}}],
    Ball[]
]
```

> 2
>
> 0
>
> 1

Comment: @Goldberg thanks for the reformatting.....@carl woll thanks for the answer and suggestion

Comment: for tangent lines region measure gives 1 instead of 0...why????

Comment: @lineage Yes, `RegionMeasure` can return the measure in any dimension. Use either `ArcLength` or `RegionMeasure[region, 1]`. I will update my answer.